# Error in chk.H2OFrame(x) : must be an H2OFrame

Tags: r, deep-learning, h2o

I have run h2o deeplearning and obtained a model as follows

```
best_model<- h2o.deeplearning( activation = "RectifierWithDropout",
                                            hidden = c(200, 200, 200, 200, 200),
                                            hidden_dropout_ratio = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1),
                                            loss = "CrossEntropy",
                                            l1 = 1e-5,
                                            epochs = EPOCHS,
                                            distribution = "multinomial",
                                            seed = 5000,
                                            balance_classes = TRUE,
                                            y = c("Churn"),
                                            x = columns,
                                            validation_frame = churn_validation,
                                            training_frame = churn_training

                                            )
```

Now I try to test it with my test data like this

```
churn_prediction <- h2o.predict(best_model, my_test)
```

I get this error:

```
Error in chk.H2OFrame(x) : must be an H2OFrame
```

Any suggestions please?

EDIT: The example from the documentation which seems to work fine

```
library(h2o)
h2o.init()
iris.hex <- as.h2o(iris)
iris.dl <- h2o.deeplearning(x = 1:4, y = 5, training_frame = iris.hex)

# now make a prediction
predictions <- h2o.predict(iris.dl, iris.hex)
```

Comment: Looks like my_test is not an H2OFrame. Did you transform my_test to an h2oframe?

Comment: @phiver The documentation examples show that we can use the output of deeplearning function directly. There is no need for explicit conversion. So I'm not sure what's wrong here.

Comment: I'm with phiver here, my_test must be an H2OFrame.  If you disagree please post the exact documentation reference that makes you think otherwise and/or create a reproducible example.

Comment: sorry, phiver and jmuhlenkamp were right. I had overlooked the my_test variable which should've been converted to an h2o frame

Answer (score 3):

Summarizing comments (answers) above: `my_test` must be an H2OFrame.  You can convert it from an R data.frame to H2OFrame by `hf <- as.h2o(my_test)`, or if you load the data from disk using `my_test <- h2o.importFile("test.csv")`, it will already be an H2OFrame without having to be copied from R memory.